# Bitwise not to how to do without ffffffff

Tags: go, bitwise-operators

When doing bitwise not, get a lot ffffffff. How to do correctly?

```
    space := "    "
    str := "12345678999298765432179.170.184.81"

    sp := len(str) % 4
    if sp > 0 {
        str = str + space[0:4-sp]
    }
    fmt.Println(str, len(str))

    hx := hex.EncodeToString([]byte(str))
    ln := len(hx)
    a, _ := strconv.ParseUint(hx[0:8], 16, 0)
    for i := 8; i < ln; i += 8 {
        b, _ := strconv.ParseUint(hx[i:i+8], 16, 0)
        a = a ^ b
    }

    xh := strconv.FormatUint(^a, 16)
    fmt.Println(xh)
```

output
ffffffffc7c7dbcb

I need only
c7c7dbcb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get a lot of leading `ff` because your `a` number in fact is only 32-bit "large" but is used "within" a 64-bit `uint64` value. (You're processing numbers with 8 hex digits = 4 bytes data = 32 bit.) It has 4 leading 0 bytes, which when negated will turn into `ff`. You can verify this with:

```
fmt.Printf("a %#x\n",a)
```

Outputs:

```
a 0x38382434
```

To get rid of those leading `ff`, convert the result to `uint32`:

```
xh := strconv.FormatUint(uint64(uint32(^a)), 16)
fmt.Println(xh)
```

(Converting back to `uint64` is because [`strconv.FormatUint()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatUint) expects / requires `uint64`.)

This outputs:

```
c7c7dbcb
```

Another option is to apply a `0xffffffff` bitmask:

```
xh = strconv.FormatUint(^a&0xffffffff, 16)
fmt.Println(xh)
```

Also note that you could print it using [`fmt.Printf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf) (or [`fmt.Sprintf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) if you need it as a `string`) where you specify `%08x` verb which also adds leading zeros should the input has more than 3 leading 0 bits (and thus `strconv.FormatUint()` would not add leading hex zeros):

```
fmt.Printf("%08x", uint32(^a))
```

This outputs the same. Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JyrEiApON1y).